# where is the edit information link in itunesconnect for update the app info

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have submitted application on iTunes but it rejected because they want demo username and password to test the app. So now i want to add username and password in review notes block but it is not editable..

Following is the process which I have done:-

1. Login on iTunes-connect.
2. Click on mange application.
3. select application

After that I m not getting "Edit information link" i m getting Metadata winch is editable when i select edit then "review notes" is present in Metadata, but it is not editable.

So Please give the proper step by step method for adding demo username and password in review notes block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must resubmit your binary - upon resubmission you'll be able to add more review notes and information. Sorry, but I'm afraid you have to go through it all again! When you resubmit it will go back into the review queue.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i don't want to resubmit it. So according to that any solution.

Comment: You may not like the answer, but that doesn't mean it's not correct :P If you don't like it, perhaps you should file a feature request with Apple. In the meantime, you'll have to resubmit your binary.