# How to resubmit an iOS app after rejection

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an iPhone App rejected by Apple. In Resolution Center the message with reason for rejection is:

> ---
>
> You can provide demo account information, including passwords, in the Review Notes section of your app metadata in iTunes
>   Connect.
>
> ---
>
> While your iTunes Connect Application State shows as Rejected, we don't require a new binary to correct this issue. Please visit
>   iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications, edit the Metadata to add
>   demo account details in the Review Notes section, and click "Save".
>   When you are done, click "Submit New Metadata" and we can resume the
>   review of your app.
>
> ---
>
> Also, at your earliest opportunity, please review the following
>   questions and provide as detailed information as you can in response.
>   The more information you can provide upfront, the sooner we can
>   complete your review.
>
> ---

So I am submitting new metadata.

Now the Question is I need to submit new Binary, As I am submitting new binary should i give  the information required by Apple in resolution Center it self?  or it is not required as I am submitting new Binary?

Update:
Here in my case Apple is asking for more information apart from demo account details and as I am submitting new binary where I should give that details in new metadata review notes or in resolution center of current version which is rejected

Comment: same as the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188955/where-is-the-edit-information-link-in-itunesconnect-for-update-the-app-info or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275140/sending-application-login-credentials-to-appstore-reviewers

Comment: hi everyone same problem my app upload apps but reject metadata error and not app demonstrate your application like  word send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a new binary stops the review process of the "old" binary anyway - so putting the information, Apple needs to properly test your app in the "Review notes" field in the meta data of your new binary will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

[Checkout the Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html)

For new binary you require add the metadata(as well as the Review Notes)again and go through all the review procedure again. For the old binary to go under review process add the comments in the already present Review Notes, this would reduce the time-frame of the review process. Hope this helps

Comment: The link you've provided in your answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you resubmit the binary, I suggest you enter a reference to the previous exchange in the Resolution Centre in the notes for the reviewer accompanying the new submission.  That way, they'll be aware of the past issue and be able to confirm whether it's been addressed.

I did this for a previous rejection, where I had to change something *and* explain more about the app, and it worked fine.

Good luck!